# When I delete a Firebase user from a Swift app, I still see the user in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here's my code:

```
func deleteAccount() {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        user.delete()
    } else {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

I call the function in a Button:

```
Button {
    viewModel.deleteAccount()
} label: {
    ...
}
```

I get the expected result in some sense. The app redirects back to the login page -- I did not include that redirect code above for the sake of simplicity.

When I try to login with that now-deleted user, my app correctly does not log me in.

But... I still see the user in Firebase. I expected that user to drop off of the list of users. But the user stays. How can I get the user to be truly deleted from Firebase?

Comment: "I still see the user in Firebase" Can you clarify *where* in Firebase you still see the user?

Comment: I just checked. The user still shows up in the Firestore database, under the list of users. But apparently not in the Authentication part... I'll have to investigate more on how to delete the user from Firestore.

Comment: As I said below in my answer: "If you're asking about other data you have previously attached to that user (for example, Firestore documents or Storage objects), those will not be automatically deleted. You have to write code for that."

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the list of users in the Firebase Auth console, just refresh that webpage.  It doesn't update automatically.  If that doesn't work, then there is a problem with the console that we can't help you with - reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to report an issue.

If you're asking about other data you have previously attached to that user (for example, Firestore documents or Storage objects), those will not be automatically deleted.  You have to write code for that.

To delete a document in Firestore, follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data).

Comment: Thanks, I have refreshed the page. But I still see the user.

Comment: Did you reach out to Firebase support to explain the issue with the console, if that is actually what you're looking at?

Comment: Got it, I realize now that you have to delete the authentication and the Firestore data separately. Thanks.